# "Idea of a" or "idea of"?

Tags: expressions

For example, is it correct to say "the idea of a deity" or "the idea of deity" when referring to the concept of deity in general?

Comment: Depends on what you mean.

Comment: It's unusual, though not unknown, to use *deity* to refer to a concept.  It's much more common to use a different word, for instance, *divinity*, to describe the condition of being like a god.

Comment: Sorry, I just used "deity" as an example. In particular, I was looking at "the idea of cognitive map first emerged in psychology in 1948" vs. "the idea of a cognitive map first emerged in psychology in 1948"

Comment: In that case you want *a*.

Comment: *A cognitive map*, *cognitive maps*, or *cognitive mapping* would all work (the last two without an article). And you should really update your question to reflect what you mean to ask.

Comment: Why didn't you ask what you really wanted? The way "deity" is treated in your sentences is NOT necessarily the same as the way "a cognitive map" would be treated, because "deity" can be a generic term, but "cognitive map" can't!  For the latter, it would be "the idea of **a** cognitive map", or "... of cognitive map**s**", or "... of cognitive **mapping** as @JasonBassford has pointed out.

Comment: I thought of updating the Q. to reflect the recent 'revelation' from Op - but that would make nonsense of existing comments, etc., so I've voted to close the Q. instead.